# How to replace values inside DataFrame columns with data from a python list?

Tags: python, pandas

as the title says, how do I replace the values in a DataFrame column?

Here is a tiny bit from my data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

outdated_list = pd.DataFrame({"country": ['Afghanistan', "Albania", "Algeria"], "cases": ["No data", "No data", "No data"],
                   "deaths": ["No data", "No data", "No data"], "recov": ["No data", "No data", "No data"],
                   "flag_scr": ["No data", "No data", "No data"]})
```

Output

```
       country    cases   deaths    recov flag_scr
0  Afghanistan  No data  No data  No data  No data
1      Albania  No data  No data  No data  No data
2      Algeria  No data  No data  No data  No data
```

And here is the list, which has the data I want to put inside the right columns:

```py
updated_list = [['Afghanistan', '40,141', '1,488', '33,561',
                 '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg/720px-Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg.png'],
                ['Albania', '16,774', '448', '10,001',
                 '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Flag_of_Albania.svg/21px-Flag_of_Albania.svg.png'],
                ['Algeria', '54,203', '1,846', '37,971',
                 '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Flag_of_Algeria.svg/720px-Flag_of_Algeria.svg.png']]
```

So to clarify, I want to replace for eg. the `Cases` value in `Afghanistan` row with value `40,141` from the list. How do I do it?
I guess it would be best to do it with a loop, because in the original code the list is much longer and not sorted as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dataframe directly from your list. You'll need to give it column names though.

```
updated_df = pd.DataFrame(updated_list, columns=outdated_list.columns)
```

If you want to actually *update* your original dataframe, as in the case if there is incomplete or extra data in your list, you can use the `update` method for dataframes.

```
outdated_list.update(updated_df)
```